# Create user related info model

Tags: python, django

I want to create web site like coursera.org. So I need to create two usertypes
like student and teacher. what is the best way to do that?

I have tried to create manually usertypes and predefine user types in models.py. But usertype does not show up in admin page. what ia am doing wrong?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Usertype(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'Usertype')
    usertype = ('Student','Teacher')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `usertype` a certain field, for example an `CharField` where you set the [**`choices`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices), like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

USERTYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Student'),
    ('T', 'Teacher')
)

class Usertype(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'Usertype')
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USERTYPE_CHOICES)
```

Note that you probably want to make the `ForeignKey` a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) instead to avoid creating two `Usertype`s for the same `User`.

It is also advisable to use [**`get_user_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) instead of referring to the `User` model directly, since that makes changing the user model more convenient, like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

USERTYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Student'),
    ('T', 'Teacher')
)

class Usertype(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), related_name='Usertype')
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USERTYPE_CHOICES)
```

In your `app/admin.py`, you will also need to "register" your model such that it shows up in the admin site:

```
# app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Usertype

admin.site.register(Usertype)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custom  ModelAdmin in `admin.py`

```
class UserTypeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'usertype',)

admin.site.register(UserType, UserTypeModel)
```

for extra info [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)